# how to check if a div has a class out of multiple classes in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic div which can generate over 1000 different classes... its a wordpress theme.

Now i am wanting to check if a div has one of 52 classes.

.bg1, .bg2, .bg3 etc etc...

I know that you can use hasClass();

But how do I check for each one and then get the value. For instance here is the div as it stands

```
<div id="wordpresspost" class="bodyclass post-id-193 wordpresswrap bg1"></div>
```

Please bare in mind I dont really know jquery :D

I was thinking it would be something like this but logically this does not make sense to me :(

```
var divclass = $("#wordpresspost").hasClass('bg1, bg2, bg3, bg4, bg5, bg6');

if(divclass == true){
    var divsclass = $(this);
}
```

I need to know the class because I want to change it, for instance i would like to .removeClass and then addClass a new class without changing the others as they are dynamic

Thanks in advance for the advice :)

Comment: I'd do `if ( elem.className.seach( re ) > -1 ) { ...`

Answer (score 14):

Use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/):

```
var divclass = $("#wordpresspost").is('.bg1, .bg2, .bg3, .bg4, .bg5, .bg6');
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector.

*Caveat with this is that if you have another class starts with bg[something] it would be impacted*

```
if($("#wordpresspost[class^=bg]").length > 0)
{
....
}
```

In order to remove it probably regex might help.

```
$("#wordpresspost[class^=bg]").each(function(){
     this.className = this.className.replace(/\bbg.*?\b/g, 'newclass');
});
```

Comment: And when it has the class "bgColorBlue", it will fail.

Comment: @PSCoder I need to know the class because I want to change it, for instance i would like to .removeClass and then addClass a new class without changing the others as they are dynamic

Answer (score 0):

```
var el = document.getElementById('wordpresspost');
var regxpr = /\b(bg(?:[1-9]|[1-4]\d|5[0-2]))\b/g, match;
while(match = regxpr.exec(el.className)){
    // match[1] contains the current matching class
    console.log(match[1]);
    // Then you can do:
        $(el).removeClass(match[1]).addClass(replacementForMatch);
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dPyNx/)

Answer (score -1):

If you are searching for bg* in only one element, you could just use simple regex.

```
 var hasBg = /bg[\d]+/.test(document.getElementById("mydiv").className);
```